# Program to re-program my keyboard?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I would like to add some special characters to my keyboard, without replacing already existing key assignments.

I thought of adding such letters as: `¯`, `²`, `±`, `‰`, `¢`, `¥` and `·`.

So I could get `¯` mark by pressing for example `CTRL + ALT + _`

What program should I get for this? Something that doesnt mess up my keyboard; just gives me the ability to **add** new key combinations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx) you can create CTRL+ALT+ combinations, here is how:

- Go to: File -> Load Existing Keyboard...
- Select "Shift states" (left) and click the wanted button on the keyboard, and then paste the mark you want to be createn when that key combination is pressed.
- Go to: Project -> Test Keyboard Layout... and test if everything is ok.
- Go to: Project -> Build DLL and Setup Package. wait until it asks to open the folder and then run the Setup.exe it created for you.
- Open Control Panel -> Regional and Language options (icon) -> Languages (tab) -> Details (button)
- Select the keyboard layout you installed from the "Default input language" (list)
- Press Apply and look for that little keyboard icon at your taskbar right side (possibly), click it and select your custom keyboard layout. Now it should work.

Note: I'm not sure about the last (three) steps, but I was able to make it work only after clicking that keyboard icon and selecting the layout from there.

---

May be the most simple solution is *KeyTweak*. There's also Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator but it's an old program and not easy to use as much as the one I suggest you.

[KeyTweak download](http://webpages.charter.net/krumsick/)

Both are presented there: Remapping the Keyboard Layout in Windows XP, Vista, and 7

[How to Remapping the Keyboard Layout in Windows XP, Vista, and 7](http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/remap-keyboard.htm)

[image]

Comment: I downloaded that, but i couldnt see a way to make combos such as CTRL+ALT+_ -> ¯

Comment: In this case you have the other option MSLKC: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx

Comment: That did the job! You might want to rearrange your answer to display the MSLKC first, since that was the correct tool.

Comment: I added more comprehensive guide for the MSKLC, if you can accept my edits that would be great. took me some time to figure out how to use the keyboard layout i created! Edit: accepted + upvoted.

Comment: I noticed a weird thing: some of the key combos i use now, works only on Notepad and nowhere else. for example CTRL+< (CTRL + VK_OEM_102). Have no clue why. Do you? Also i noticed that CTRL+SHIFT+5 works randomly... sometimes it works, sometimes it doesnt o_O

Comment: Hi Rookie: accepted! :)